# VB.net 2010 dataset updates but access database remains same

Tags: vb.net

I have tried to `insert or update` from my `vb.net` form into `MS-Access` database.

The dataset updates but the `access` database wont. Below is my code.

```
    Try
            Dim addLocation As String = "Insert into Provider (StateCode, Provider)" _
            & "values ('" & ComboBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "')"
            Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand
            conn.Open()
            With sqlcommand
                .CommandText = addLocation
                .Connection = conn
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("One record added", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            refreshGrid()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    Private Sub refreshGrid() 
        cnString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source =" & Application.StartupPath & "\HCHPClosedIn.accdb" 
        sqlQRY = "SELECT * FROM Provider" 
        conn = New OleDbConnection(cnString) 
      Try 
        conn.Open() 
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQRY, conn) 
        Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da) 
        da.Fill(ds, "Customers") 
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds 
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "Customers"
      End Try
   End Sub
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error.. It just does not add to database. The Dataset updates though because i use it in a datagridview.

Comment: Post you refreshgrid code

Comment: Private Sub refreshGrid()

cnString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source =" & Application.StartupPath & "\HCHPClosedIn.accdb"

sqlQRY = "SELECT * FROM Provider"

conn = New OleDbConnection(cnString)

Try
            conn.Open()

            da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQRY, conn)

            Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

            da.Fill(ds, "Customers")

            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

 DataGridView1.DataMember = "Customers"

 Catch ex As OleDbException

 MsgBox(ex.ToString)

 Finally

 conn.Close()

 End Try

Comment: did you use Databine method in refreshgrid

Comment: No i did not.I am sorry for the formatting of the code i pasted here.

Comment: I have added solution below check with that

Comment: you have selected from provider but the datagridview loads customer, is the values in the grid are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a while but I think I recall Access is kinda picky with commit.   Try this:

```
With sqlcommand
     .CommandText = addLocation
     .Connection = conn
     .ExecuteNonQuery()
     .transaction = trans 
End With

Trans.Commit()
```